# Dynamic mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I need help creating a method for dynamic mysqli prepared statements. The code below has errors. I know I'm completely off with the way mysqli_stmt_bind_param is set up but I can't figure out a solution. My coding style is probably strange since I'm using OO php, but procedural mysqli. I haven't had the time to figure out OO mysqli since the books and videos I read/watch use procedural mysqli. Most of the solutions I've seen for this problem use OO mysqli. I'd prefer to get a short-term fix for this rather than having to learn PDO after I spent so much time learning mysqli.

```
public function create($sql, $param_type, $param){
    //param_type should be set as $param_type = "'ssss'" so that single quotes get passed into the variable
    //param should be an array
    //param array items should be escaped
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->dbc, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $param_type, join(array_values($param), ", "));
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if($result){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use OO mysqli is simple:

1. Change every `mysqli_blah($this->dbc)` call to `$this->dbc->blah()`.
2. Change every `mysqli_stmt_blah($stmt)` call to `$stmt->blah()`.
3. Profit!

Also, *always* check the return value from `prepare()` and `execute()`.  They return false when there's an error in parsing or execution, and you need to check for these and report errors *every time*.

The `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` function is tricky because it expects a variable number of arguments, one for each letter in the param type argument, *not* a string of comma-separated values.  Also, it requires you pass variables by reference, not scalars, and not a single array.

- WRONG: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", "red,green,blue");`
- WRONG: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", "red", "green", "blue");`
- WRONG: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_array);`
- RIGHT: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param1, $param2, $param3);`

This makes it difficult and confusing to do what you're doing: writing a general-purpose function to prepare and execute an SQL statement with a dynamic number of parameters.  You have to use `call_user_func_array()` but you have to rewrite the array of arguments as an array of references.

I wrote examples in a couple of my past SO answers:

- [How to bind an arbitrary number of values to a prepared statement in mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931394/how-to-bind-an-arbitrary-number-of-values-to-a-prepared-statement-in-mysqli/15933696#15933696)
- [mysqli_prepare vs PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383335/mysqli-prepare-vs-pdo/7383439#7383439)

PDO solves this much more easily, you don't have bind anything, you just pass an array to `execute()`.